# Get lan&lon and values from GeoTIFF using Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, coordinates, land-cover

I have GeoTIFF images from https://esa-worldcover.org/en

My goal is to get a list of latitude / longitude / value from that image. The value is a numeric attribute which represents a class as explained in https://worldcover2020.esa.int/data/docs/WorldCover_PUM_V1.1.pdf

I could get the value from each pixel by doing:

```
import rasterio
img=r'ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_N39E000_Map.tif'
ds = rasterio.open(img)
data=ds.read()
```

However, when I'm trying to link those values from lat and lon (after transforming x and y values to lat and lon), the shape doesn't fit.

The code I've used for transforming x and y into coordinates is:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp

with rasterio.open('ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_N39E000_Map.tif') as dataset:

    # Read the dataset's valid data mask as a ndarray.
    mask = dataset.dataset_mask()
    
    # Extract feature shapes and values from the array.
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(
            mask, transform=dataset.transform):
    
        # Transform shapes from the dataset's own coordinate
        # reference system to CRS84 (EPSG:4326).
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
            dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=8)
```

I only get 13213 values. How is it possible? The map can be downloaded in [here](https://viewer.esa-worldcover.org/worldcover/?language=en&bbox=-8.933619780586396,37.67901866369024,5.159968233923723,42.56709736030916&overlay=false&bgLayer=MapBox_Satellite&date=2022-04-12&layer=WORLDCOVER_2020_MAP)

Comment: `rasterio.features.shapes` returns connected groups of pixels of the same value, not individual pixels. Just convert your tiff to XYZ e.g `gdal_translate -of XYZ input.tif output.xyz` then read it in with pandas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the job...

(There's no need to obtain all coordinates of the raster first (which would be more than 1 billion in this case...)

```py
import rasterio
dat = rasterio.open(r"ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_N45W120_Map.tif")
# read all the data from the first band
z = dat.read()[0]

# check the crs of the data
dat.crs
# >>> CRS.from_epsg(4326)

# check the bounding-box of the data
dat.bounds
# >>> Out[49]: BoundingBox(left=-120.0, bottom=45.0, right=-117.0, top=48.0)

# since the raster is in regular lon/lat grid (4326) we can use 
# `dat.index()` to identify the index of a given lon/lat pair
# (e.g. it expects coordinates in the native crs of the data)

def getval(lon, lat):
    idx = dat.index(lon, lat, precision=1E-6)    
    return dat.xy(*idx), z[idx]

getval(-118, 46)
# >>> ((-117.99995833333334, 46.00004166666667), 10)
```

... and so we found that (-118, 46) seems to be covered by Trees :-)

[image]